# How do you traverse int[][]?

Tags: traversal

I tried doing:

```
for (int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
  for (int j=0; j<matrix[].length; j++) {
```

but that doesn't work :(

Comment: well actually if it's a square matrix, then it's easy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just index into the matrix using your current row.

```
for (int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
  for (int j=0; j<matrix[i].length; j++) {
    // code
  }
}
```

This even factors in the possibility of a [jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) (i.e., a matrix with an inconsistent number of rows in the column).

Answer (score 5):

```
for (int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<matrix[i].length; j++) {
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++) {
  for (int j=0; j<matrix[i].length; j++) {
```

Notice the `i` I added.

However, it's best to cache both lengths while looping to avoid re-evaluation on each loop, which saves time at the only cost of one more `int` in memory (the fix still applies):

```
for (int i=0, il=matrix.length; i<il; i++) {
  for (int j=0, jl=matrix[i].length; j<jl; j++) {
```

Comment: Note that caching the array lengths will only work if the array won't resize in the loop.

Comment: That's true. It's good for if you're not changing the size, but only reading or writing.